# Is there a better way to extract values from this JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I have found this example in https://www.sqlshack.com/extract-scalar-values-from-json-data-using-json_value/

```
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @data = N'{
    "Employees": [
        {
            "EmpName": "Rohan Sharma",
            "Department": "IT",
            "Address": "101, Sector 5, Gurugram, India",
            "Salary": 100000
        },
        {
            "EmpName": "Manohar Lal",
            "Department": "Human Resources",
            "Address": "17, Park Avenue, Mumbai, India",
            "Salary": 78000
        }
    ]
}';
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[0].EmpName') AS 'Name', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[0].Department') AS 'Department', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[0].Address') AS 'Address', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[0].Salary') AS 'Salary'
UNION ALL
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[1].EmpName') AS 'Name', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[1].Department') AS 'Department', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[1].Address') AS 'Address', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[1].Salary') AS 'Salary'
```

So I wonder if there are better ways to get all values in JSON without telling `$.Employees` indexes?

Example, if I have N components in this JSON, I don't want to have to `UNION ALL` N times.

In my project there will be like more than 40 components in a single JSON.

```
DECLARE @data NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @data = N'{
    "Employees": [
        {
            "EmpName": "Rohan Sharma",
            "Department": "IT",
            "Address": "101, Sector 5, Gurugram, India",
            "Salary": 100000
        },
        {
            "EmpName": "Manohar Lal",
            "Department": "Human Resources",
            "Address": "17, Park Avenue, Mumbai, India",
            "Salary": 78000
        },
        {
            "EmpName": "Emp 03",
            "Department": "Demo",
            "Address": "Address03",
            "Salary": 9999
        },
        {
            "EmpName": "Emp 04",
            "Department": "Demo",
            "Address": "Address04",
            "Salary": 9999
        },
        {
            "EmpName": "Emp N",
            "Department": "Demo",
            "Address": "AddressN",
            "Salary": 9999
        }
    ]
}';
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[0].EmpName') AS 'Name', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[0].Department') AS 'Department', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[0].Address') AS 'Address', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[0].Salary') AS 'Salary'
UNION ALL
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[1].EmpName') AS 'Name', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[1].Department') AS 'Department', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[1].Address') AS 'Address', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[1].Salary') AS 'Salary'
UNION ALL
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[2].EmpName') AS 'Name', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[2].Department') AS 'Department', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[2].Address') AS 'Address', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[2].Salary') AS 'Salary'
UNION ALL
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[3].EmpName') AS 'Name', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[3].Department') AS 'Department', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[3].Address') AS 'Address', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[3].Salary') AS 'Salary'
UNION ALL
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[N].EmpName') AS 'Name', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[N].Department') AS 'Department', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[N].Address') AS 'Address', 
       JSON_VALUE(@data, '$.Employees[N].Salary') AS 'Salary'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `OPENJSON` and specify the schema using `WITH` something like this.  The 'EmpName' column is read in from the JSON and renamed to 'Name'

```
select *
from openjson(@data, N'$.Employees') 
     with (Name      nvarchar(200) N'strict $.EmpName',
           Department   nvarchar(20),
           [Address]    nvarchar(20),
           Salary       nvarchar(20));
```

```
Name            Department      Address                 Salary
Rohan Sharma    IT              101, Sector 5, Gurug    100000
Manohar Lal     Human Resources 17, Park Avenue, Mum    78000
Emp 03          Demo            Address03               9999
Emp 04          Demo            Address04               9999
Emp N           Demo            AddressN                9999
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have JSON text's that stored in database table you can read or modify JSON values by using built in functions like

- ISJSON (Transact-SQL) tests whether a string contains valid JSON.
- JSON_VALUE (Transact-SQL) extracts a scalar value from a JSON string.
- JSON_QUERY (Transact-SQL) extracts an object or an array from a JSON
  string.
- JSON_MODIFY (Transact-SQL) changes a value in a JSON string.

Below example will extract Empname and Department from JSonCol (column with JSON Value)

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(jsonCol, '$.Employee.EmpName') AS Empname,
JSON_VALUE(jsonCol, '$.Employee.Deapartment') As Department
FROM Table_Name
Where ISJSON(JsonCol)>0;
```